# PROTOCOL_TLS error with urllib in IronPython

Tags: python, urllib, ironpython

I am working with a python script that is loaded by a twitch bot.  The bot, unfortunately, does not include a logic handler for if then else, but thankfully has python scripting support to handle logic outside of the bot.

when using urllib.urlopen after importing urllib this error returns:

Message: global name 'PROTOCOL_TLS' is not defined

I've built the code external to the bot in an IDE and the code is executing fine so it appears to be something special that needs to be done for IronPython to handle the call rather than the regular Python.

The entire script file contains additional information that goes back to the integration, but the whole file is:

```
#---------------------------------------
# Import Libraries
#---------------------------------------

import os
import urllib

#---------------------------------------
#         Version History
#---------------------------------------
# 1.0.0.0 Initial Release.

#---------------------------------------
# Variables
#---------------------------------------
SettingsFile = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "SCShoutoutSettings.json")

#---------------------------------------
# Classes
#---------------------------------------
class Settings(object):
    def __init__(self, settingsfile=None):
        try:
            with codecs.open(settingsfile, encoding="utf-8-sig", mode="r") 
as f:
                self.__dict__ = json.load(f, encoding="utf-8")
        except:
            self.Enabled = True
            self.Command = "!so"
            self.CD_Time = 0
            self.Permissions = "Moderator"
            self.Fee = False
            self.Cost = 0

    def Reload(self, jsondata):
        self.__dict__ = json.loads(jsondata, encoding="utf-8")
    return

def Save(self, settingsfile):
    try:
        with codecs.open(settingsfile, encoding="utf-8-sig", mode="w+") as f:
            json.dump(self.__dict__, f, encoding="utf-8", ensure_ascii=False)
        with codecs.open(settingsfile.replace("json", "js"), encoding="utf-8-sig", mode="w+") as f:
            f.write("var settings = {0};".format(json.dumps(self.__dict__, encoding='utf-8', ensure_ascii=False)))
    except:
        Parent.Log(ScriptName, "Failed to save settings to file.")
    return

#---------------------------------------
# Initialize Data on Load
#---------------------------------------
def Init():
    global ScriptSettings
    ScriptSettings = Settings(SettingsFile)
    return

#---------------------------------------
# Reload Settings on Save
#---------------------------------------
def ReloadSettings(jsondata):
    ScriptSettings.Reload(jsondata)
    return

#---------------------------------------
#    Script is going to be unloaded
#---------------------------------------
def Unload():
    ScriptSettings.Save(SettingsFile)
    return

#---------------------------------------
#    Script is enabled or disabled on UI
#---------------------------------------
def ScriptToggled(state):
    if not state:
        ScriptSettings.Save(SettingsFile)
    return

#---------------------------------------
# Execute data and process messages
#---------------------------------------
 def Execute(data):

    if data.IsChatMessage():
        global ScriptSettings
        if data.GetParam(0).lower() == ScriptSettings.Command:
        target = data.GetParam(1)
        gameLink = "http://customapi.deepbot.tv/streamgame/" + target
        followLink = "http://customapi.deepbot.tv/totalfollows/" + target
        twitchLink = "https://twitch.tv/" + target
        gameSock = urllib.urlopen(gameLink)
        followSock = urllib.urlopen(followLink)
        game = gameSock.read()
        gameSock.close()
        follow = followSock.read()
        followSock.close()
        if game == "Error reaching Twitch API.":
            message = target + " is not a streamer"
        else:
            message = "Check out " + target + " the last game they were playing was " + game + " they have " + follow + " followers, why not add some more?  Go to " + twitchLink

        Parent.SendStreamMessage(message)
return

#---------------------------------------
# Tick
#---------------------------------------
def Tick():
    return

#---------------------------------------
# SetDefaults Custom User Interface Button
#---------------------------------------
def SetDefaults():

    # Globals
    global ScriptSettings

    # Set defaults by not supplying a settings file
    ScriptSettings = Settings()

    # Save defaults back to file
    ScriptSettings.Save(SettingsFile)

    # End of SetDefaults
    return
```

Answer (score 1):

this is caused by an issue in IronPython, the python version that is used in streamlabs chatbot (yea i know you're talking about that one ^^ ). It is a problem in the ssl module that urllib uses. This is also the reason why chatbot forsees the following functions:

https://github.com/AnkhHeart/Streamlabs-Chatbot-Python-Boilerplate/wiki/API-Requests

i am looking for a solution myself, but so far i've had to rewrite everything to use these functions. This is the same reason why urllib2, requests and many other modules will not work.

Comment: i think, but am not sure, that upgrading ironpython to the latest version might solve this. The latest ironpython version came out in february of this yea, right before you opened the question. also make sure u have ironpython stdlib linked and not cpython. Let me know if it helped